# How to change part of an url in php?

Tags: php, replace

I am new to PHP and I am trying to work on this one problem where the middle of a URL changes.

For instance using this fake URL,

```
$url = 'http://www.bobsplace.com/events/georgetown/12354544233123';
```

I need to be able to substitute "georgetown" out with a random variable.

So I guess I need to like slice the URL after events, have a variable where "georgetown" would be, and then have the rest of the URL continue after it. I hope I am making as much sense as possible.

Alright,
  I tried all these and still go errors, but most likely it is due to my current coding.  I am entering the entire thing in now.

```
<?

// This URL only shows future events

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/192674347443031/events?access_token=153420758043439|66d692f0e73ad17d939d9d9c-1045402872|8VHLfMb3gYY0p9fnT7wMS8Q9Krc&expires_in=0&since=yesterday' ;

$event_id = get_post_custom_values('facebook_id');
$url = str_replace('/192674347443031/', '/' . $event_id . '/', $url);


$json = file_get_contents($url) ;

$data = json_decode( $json,true) ; 
//var_dump($data) ; 

$sorted_array = array_reverse($data['data'], TRUE) ; 

foreach ($sorted_array as $key => $value) {

    //print_r($value) ; 
    ?>

<? echo "<li><a href='http://facebook.com/event.php?eid=". $value['id']  . "' target='_blank'>" ;  
                                        echo "<h2>" .  $value['name'] . "</h2>" ;
                                        echo "</a>" ;
                                        echo " (" . $value['location'] .") <br />" ; 
                                        echo date("F j, Y, g:i a" , strtotime($value['start_time'])) . " to " . date("F j, Y, g:i a" , strtotime($value['end_time'])) ;?>
                                    <div class="moreinfo">    
                                     <? echo "<a href='http://facebook.com/event.php?eid=". $value['id']  . " ' target='_blank'>" ; 
                                        echo "<b>" .  'More info' . "</b>" ;
                                        echo "</a>" ;?>
                                        </div>
                                        <? echo "</li>"; 


}



?>
```

The errors I keep getting are now saying my array_reverse() should be an array.  And also invalid argument foreach()

Now this is not the entire code on that page, but this is the snippet that is giving me problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to say that you want to replace the text "georgetown". If that's correct, the following code should work (make sure you've defined $replace to what you want to replace it with):

```
$url = str_replace('/georgetown/', '/' . $replace . '/', $url);
```

Comment: Adding slashes around it would make it safer.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to replace the string between the last two forward slashes, not the actual word "georgetown".

Comment: @Alix Given the URL, I didn't think that would be likely, but I've made the change just in case. Thanks.

Comment: @FreekOne: You're probably right, this question is a bit vague.

Comment: Sorry for it being vague.  What I am meaning to do is have georgetown substituted with multiple different things depending what the user inputs in for that variable.

Answer (score 7):

you can do :

```
$url = 'http//:www.bobsplace.com/events/georgetown/12354544233123';
$my_var = 'foobar';

$url = str_replace("georgetown", $my_var, $url );
```

or :

```
$url = 'http//:www.bobsplace.com/events/georgetown/12354544233123';
$my_var = 'foobar';

$temp = explode( '/'  , $url );
$temp[4] = $my_var;
$url = implode( '/' , $temp );
```

First one will replace by name , second one by position in URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = 'place'; //e.g. georgetown
$url = 'http:www.bobsplace.com/events/'.$variable.'/12354544233123';
```

I think this is what you're asking for.